# Verlet integration first step

Tags: integration

I'm trying to implement color-to-grayscale method from [this paper](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~oliveira/pubs_files/MS_C2G/Kuhn_Oliveira_Color_to_Gray_TVCJ_Pre-print.pdf). And they use Verlet's integration as:

$$L^*(t+\Delta t)=\frac{F(t)}{m}\Delta t^2+2L^*(t)-L^*(t-\Delta t),$$

for computing new value of luminance. But they not say how to compute new value of luminance for $t=0$. According to [this Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration) I think it could be as:

$$L^*(\Delta t)=\frac{F(0)}{2m}\Delta t^2+L^*(0)$$

Is it correct?

Comment: At time zero, no integration has happened yet, right? So there's some initial state before doing any integration; isn't that described in the paragraph starting with "The instantaneous force applied to a particle..."

Answer (score -1):

The function varies as you increase the time step ∆t , t will be zero from the start, So at ∆t =0, the initial condition L*(0) is the gray scale value obtained by converting the color image into L* a* b*  color space.

Comment: I don't think that $\Delta t$ should be set to 0. Because $\Delta t$ represents time difference between current value and next value, so if i want to compute new value after 0.01 seconds pass, i would set $\Delta t$ to 0.01. I use fixed timestep so $\Delta t$ is constant. You are right that $L^*(0)$ is obtained from the image.